# Paragraphs don't have enough height when export JasperReports PDF in Amazon EC2 suse Linux

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, itext

Just the image shows, I use JasperReports 3.6, iText 2.1, and iTextAsian.jar.
PDF export is correct on Mac(Lion) and Windows 7. But when I run the sam program on Suse Linux in Amazon EC2.
The PDF goes wrong with insufficient height.
I tried to use the same true type font, but problem remains.

Please advise, thank you very much.

[image: Comparison between correct and wrong PDF output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it done. It is all about 'font' file.

I don't find any Chinese font installed within Amazon EC2 Suse Linux, so that I copied one of my Chinese font file on to EC2 linux.

You can just put your desired font file under ~/.fonts folder. (If not exists, create it.) Remember to restart your EC2 linux so that new font type can take effect.

For example the font file is "MingLiU.ttf"

Now turn back to your iReport editor, be sure to change your text field property setting "fontName" to "MingLiU". So that JasperReports can use this font type to calculate accurate paragraph height.

It is nothing to do with "pdfFontName". All paragraph height are determined when processing .jasper file into JasperPrint object. "pdfFontName" is only used to export JasperPrint to PDF file.